# xcodebuild not doing incremental builds

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, incremental-build

I recently checked out a fresh version of our iOS app from git and built from command line via `xcodebuild`. I then built a second time using the exact same command, **while making no changes to files in the repo whatsoever (not even opening them).**

I expected the second build to take no time at all, but it actually took longer than the first:

```
user$ time xcodebuild -sdk 'iphonesimulator' -scheme 'DemoApp' -configuration 'Debug' -target 'DemoApp' build > /dev/null

real    5m45.849s
user    0m15.270s
sys     0m5.640s

user$ time xcodebuild -sdk 'iphonesimulator' -scheme 'DemoApp' -configuration 'Debug' -target 'DemoApp' build > /dev/null

real    6m8.858s
user    0m12.904s
sys     0m4.198s
```

**If I do builds in xcode with no changes, it builds and runs in a matter of seconds.**

Here are things I've tried to get incremental builds on command line:

- I tried adding `-derivedDataPath ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, but got the same results.
- I've added the `-incremental` flag to other Swift arguments.
- I've turned off all shell scripts and ensured no files have changed between builds

**Does `xcodebuild` not support incremental builds? Is there a way to figure out why this is happening?**

I'm using the latest Xcode and the new Xcode 10 build system. Most of the code is in swift if that makes any difference.

**Edit: changing back to the old build system builds incrementally via `xcodebuild` in under 30 seconds.**

---

Update:

The way I'm testing this: I have a Jenkins job that will clone the repo and do a hard clean: running xcodebuild clean and deleting the build directory and and derived data directory by hand just in case. Then it does a build. Then it makes no changes and does a build again. The second build is the one I'm timing.

Comment: Is the project in a workspace? If it is, did you try to pass the workspace as an argument? In a test I just did, it drops to ~4 seconds for subsequent builds of a ~3 minute initial build.

Comment: Could you try removing `-target`? Target shouldn't be there since you are using scheme.

Comment: Is it possible some script (either in scheme or in project) is updating some files? e.g. are you using sourcery? Also make sure that your project does not have `Compilation Mode` set to `Whole Module`.

Comment: @Sulthan I'll give that a try

Comment: @Sulthan I tried removing -target, but that was no change. I also turned off swift optimization and changed complication mode to incremental but still no change.

Comment: And no scripts. I have a jenkins job set up and I run a finder command before and after a do-nothing build to ensure no files have changed at all.

Comment: if you are using Cocoapods. it will rebuild all the frameworks from scratch and cause the huge delay in building iOS project

Comment: Will Cocoapods rebuild all the frameworks *even on incremental builds* ? I can't find any documentation online regarding this.